# How to insert record ID instead of Varchar to my MySql using JComboBox in JAVA Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

[image][image]

Hi,

I would like to ask a help regarding adding entries using JComboBox to MySql database. The thing is, I have multiple table in my database and most of them are in relationships.

Example:

Employee_Details table, it has 3 Foreign Keys which is from another table such as Position,Department and Office_Location. Now these Foreign keys has data type values of INT, now the problem is, if I select one of the given character value inside the combobox and hit save it will give me an error because it's clearly does not match with the assigned data type in the employee_details database table.

Question:

How can I select any given character values inside the combobox and when I click the add or insert button then it will save the ID of that value instead of the variable character.

```
private void Position(){ // Position Combo Box

     try {
         String sqlPosition = "Select * From positions";
         pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlPosition);
         rs = pst.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){

             JCB_Position.addItem(rs.getString("Position"));


         }

     } catch (SQLException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
 }

 private boolean CheckInputs(){

     if(jTextFieldFname.getText() != null || jTextFieldLname.getText() !=null || JCB_Department.getSelectedItem() != null 
             || JCB_Location.getSelectedItem() != null
             || JCB_Location.getSelectedItem() != null
             || JCB_EmpStat.getSelectedItem() !=null
             )
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;  
 }

private void jButtonAddEmpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    int InsertToDB = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save this entry?", "SAVE",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (InsertToDB == 0)
    {

        String Gender = null;

        if(JRB_Male.isSelected())
        {
            Gender = "Male";
        }
        else if(JRB_Female.isSelected())
        {
            Gender = "Female";
        }

        jTextFieldFname.getText();
        jTextFieldLname.getText();
        jTextFieldOfficeNumber.getText();
        jTextFieldMobNumber.getText();
        jTextFieldEmailAdd.getText();
        jTextAreaRemarks.getText();
        String Position = JCB_Position.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //String Dept = JCB_Department.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //String Loc = JCB_Location.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //String Status = JCB_EmpStat.getSelectedItem().toString();   

        if(CheckInputs() != false)
        {
            try {
                pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee_details (First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, "
                        + "Office_Number, Mobile_Number, Email_Address, Remarks)"
                        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setString(1, jTextFieldFname.getText());
                pst.setString(2, jTextFieldLname.getText());
                pst.setString(3, Gender);
               //pst.setInt(4, Position);
                //pst.setString(5, Dept);
                //pst.setString(6, Loc);
                //pst.setString(7, Status);
                pst.setString(4, jTextFieldOfficeNumber.getText());
                pst.setString(5, jTextFieldMobNumber.getText());
                pst.setString(6, jTextFieldEmailAdd.getText());
                pst.setString(7, jTextAreaRemarks.getText());

                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Succesfully Saved");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Employee_Details.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check the mandatory fields");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the part of the code where you fill the combobox with values

Comment: Please check the code attached above, That is the code for the add button.
Note: I did not assign any action listener to any of the combo boxes. All the codes are assigned only in the Add button.

Comment: That's the code executed when the button is clicked, I need to see the code where you put the values that can be selected into the combobox (JCB_Position). You should also follow java naming conventions and use lowercase names for your variables, uppercase (such as your variable "Gender") is usually used for class names and may lead to conflicts if used like this

Comment: There, I re edit it again. I can handle the naming and conventions. I just need to know how can I overcome that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are adding Strings to your JComboBox, so no association to the id remains.

You could create a wrapper class like this:

```
public class PositionWrapper {
    private int id;
    private String position;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

and add it to your JComboBox like this:

```
while(rs.next()){
    PositionWrapper position = new PositionWrapper();
    position.setId(rs.getInt("Position_ID"));
    position.setPosition(rs.getString("Position"));
    JCB_Position.addItem(position);
}
```

The JComboBox will use the `toString()` method of the `PositionWrapper` as the content, but using `JCB_Position.getSelectedItem()` will now return a `PositionWrapper`.

Now simply get the id from there:

```
pst.setInt(0, ((PositionWrapper)JCB_Position.getSelectedItem()).getId());
```

If your JComboBox is editable then you need to check the type of the returned object first or you may receive an exception.

You will need to adjust the type of your JComboBox to `JComboBox<PositionWrapper>`.

Comment: I'm getting an error at the `JCB_Position.addItem(EmpPos);`

Error:

incompatible types:Employee_details.PositionWrapper cannot be converted to String.

Comment: Here is my code I change some naming and conventions.

`while(rs.next()){
                 
                 PositionWrapper EmpPos = new PositionWrapper();
                 EmpPos.setID(rs.getInt("Position_ID"));
                 EmpPos.setPosition("Position");
                 JCB_Position.addItem(EmpPos);`

Comment: You have to change the type of the JComboBox like I said - If you are using a GUI Editor you should do it there, if not you need to change the line that looks like `JComboBox JCB_Position = new JComboBox()` or something similar.

Comment: `pst.setInt(4, Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem().getid);`

The getid isn't working. That is the only error I'm getting right now.

Comment: Do I need to call the PotsitionWrapper Class inside the `private void jButtonAddEmpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` method?

Comment: The class should be in it's own file. And what's the error you're getting? If you're spelling it like you did in the comment, that is a problem: It needs to be `.getId()` and not `.getid`

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the open and close parenthesis in my previous comment. but in my line of code there is a parenthesis after the getid.
`pst.setInt(4, Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem().getid());`

the error is:   Cannot find symbol
Symbol: method getId()
Location: Class Object

Comment: Yes, because it is `.getId()` with a capital i. And from what the error is telling me you still haven't updated the declaration of the JComboBox.

Comment: private int id;

`public int GetId(){
            return id;
        }`

That is my method inside the PositionWrapper Class.

Comment: Then you also need to call `Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem().GetId()` and not `Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem().getid()`. Java is case-sensitive. But this will still not work unless you update the type of your JComboBox.

Comment: what do you mean declaration? by changing the variable name of the combo box in on it's properties?

Comment: If you are using a GUI Editor then you need to search for something like "Type Parameters" in the properties of the JComboBox and set it to "Position". If you are creating the JComboBox yourself you need to search for the line that looks like `JComboBox<String> Emp_Position = new JComboBox<>()` or similar and change it so `JComboBox<Position> Emp_Position = new JComboBox<>()`

Comment: I found this in this at the bottom of the codes `private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> Emp_Positions;` but the problem is I cannot modify it becuase I use the drag and drop from the palette tools. I use JAVA Netbeans. I right click the combobox and select properties but I couldn't find there the option to change or update the variable declaration.

Comment: If you use Netbeans then you can change the Type Parameter in the "Code"-Tab next to the properties, it should look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xoGirO6.png) but in your case it needs to be `<PositionWrapper>`.

Comment: Done! I update the variable declaration and this code also work. `JCB_Position.addItem(EmpPos);` the EmpPos is from `PositionWrapper EmpPos = new PositionWrapper();`. now the only problem is the `pst.setInt(4, Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem().GetId());`. the `GetId()` is the same naming I have used in my `public int GetId(){
            return id;
        }` Method, just like what you told me.

Comment: I'm still getting an error with the `.GetId();` column. and one more thing, isn't it going to appear as suggestion when I hold down the shift key and press space after `getSelectedItem()` and the dot. In my case there is no GetId() suggestion only getClass().

Comment: I've checked the JComboBox again and you're right, it seems you need to cast it to PositionWrapper first because an editable JComboBox could return a different value. Try changing your code to this and see if it works:
`pst.setInt(4, ((PositionWrapper)Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem()).getId());`

Comment: `pst.setInt(4, ((PositionWrapper)Emp_Positions.getSelectedItem()).getId());` Problem solved. but now I'm getting this error when trying to insert data. `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Office_Number, Mobile_Number, Email_Address, Remarks)VALUES ('Alex','Johnson' at line 1`. Do you have any idea what might be the cause of this error.

Comment: That error is caused by a mistake in your SQL statement but the SQL in your code looks correct to me. Unless your SQL has changed I don't see the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll check my DB later because it's 2am in the morning here. By the I really appreciate your help, until next time.